# android firebase listall() file names stored in storage as string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an android firebase project in which I want to get a list of all the files stored in the firebase storage. I say this question on stackoverflow and I am trying to use the listAll function (see the answer by Rosário Pereira). However, I cannot figure out how to get a list of all the files prefixes as a string. If I use storageReference.listall() function, does this function returns the list of all the files? I am using the firebase-storage version 18.1.1.

Below, I have included the code that I have written. I am stuck inside the button2 setOnClickListener function.

```
package com.example.retrieveimage;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.ListResult;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image;
Button button, button2;
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference sr = storage.getReference().child("image.jpg");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
button = findViewById(R.id.fetchImage);
button2 = findViewById(R.id.getCount);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            final File file = File.createTempFile("image", "jpg");
            sr.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IMAGE failed to Load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IMAGE FAILED TO LOAD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        StorageReference sr1 = storage.getReference().child(""); //Images are in the default folder
        // I am stuck here

        String prompt = "The total number of Images is a";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, prompt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

}
```

Comment: The first thing to do is review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files).  After that, please edit the question to show that code that isn't working the way you expect.  Please explain clearly what is actually happening and how that's different than what is suggested by the documentation.

Comment: @DougStevenson The question clearly states what is happening and what is needed. Maybe you need to read it again. All I need is to display the list of all the files. I have read the documentation multiple times and it doesnt say anywhere how to retrieve the list of files AS A STRING

Comment: The question just says "If I use storageReference.listall() function, does this function returns the list of all the files?"  It does say what the list of files is expected to be, and it doesn't show the code that uses listall, so we have no idea if you're using it correctly or what went wrong.  I recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example